# Understanding Javascript __proto__ etc

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, prototype-programming

I'm altering a node module, and it delves into a portion of JS I don't understand.  Unfortunately, it's also difficult to find documentation that explains what's going on here or why someone would do this.

Context: This code takes a json response from a database, which can come in several forms and does some manipulation before returning it.  In this particular case, the json response has an attribute "rows" with an array of objects in it.  The json response also has some attributes like "total_rows" that give added information about the db.

```
if (json.rows) {
        obj           = json.rows.slice(0);
        obj.__proto__ = new(Array);
        if (json && typeof json === 'object') {
            Object.keys(json).forEach(function (k) {
                Object.defineProperty(obj.__proto__, k, {
                    value:      json[k],
                    enumerable: false
                });
            });
        }
}// elseifs for other forms of json
```

I'm trying to understand this, and this is what I've come up with.  Please, tell me if I'm understanding this correctly...

The slice does a shallow copy, making a new array that is effectively the array housed in json.rows.

I have no idea what the purpose of the `__proto__ = new(Array)` is.

Then, there's a needless check to see if json exists (it would have to for the `if(json.rows)` to pass) and a check to see if json is an object (is this needless or is it possible that it's not just an object?  is there something else it could be and still have json.rows?).

Then, it iterates through the keys and adds them as properties on the obj.  As far as I can tell, this makes a new special array object with these additional properties that are accessible through obj.propertyName.

The result is a new kind of array that is populated with the contents of json.rows that also has properties for all the other keys in json.  That way, it's possible to iterate through the array, but it's also possible to get the other data like json.total_rows.

If, instead, the json was returned unaltered, you would have to iterate through json.rows, instead of just json.  Is that correct?  Does it do more than that?  If so, what and why might someone do that?

Sorry for the long question, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Where exactly have you found this (link please)? Without context, it looks like nonsense.

Comment: What happens to `obj`?

Comment: It comes from here: https://github.com/flatiron/cradle/blob/master/lib/cradle/database/views.js

obj gets returned as the result of the db call.  I was returning that to the client, but I realized this special structure means that all the extra properties are lost when I convert obj to a json response.

Comment: Actually that code is found in https://github.com/flatiron/cradle/blob/master/lib/cradle/response.js

Comment: Do you know *what* `obj.__proto__ = new(Array)` does (not what the purpose is)?

Comment: If I understand the documentation and what I've read correctly, it copies the prototype of Array to this object, effectively making obj capable of producing new objects that are identical to new arrays.  I'm having trouble finding documentation that describes this really well though.

Comment: No, it copies a new array (`[]`) [*as the prototype*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) of `obj`. Total rubbish if you ask me. I think you should file a bug an ask the author of the library, not on StackOverflow.